# Compare values and print key from Python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a list of `OrderedDict`'s and I want to find a matching subset from a second `OrderedDict`.

```
d1 = [
    OrderedDict([('name', 'John'), ('Score1', '2'), ('Score2', '8'), ('Score3', '3')]),
    OrderedDict([('name', 'Jack'), ('Score1', '4'), ('Score2', '1'), ('Score3', '5')]),
    OrderedDict([('name', 'Jill'), ('Score1', '1'), ('Score2', '2'), ('Score3', '5')])
]
    
d2 = OrderedDict([('Score1', '4'), ('Score2', '1'), ('Score3', '5')])
```

How can I compare these dictionaries, find the correct entry, and then print the name? In this case, we should get "Jack".

Comment: Please edit your question to fix errors and to clarify. `Dict1` doesn't make sense: currently, it sort of looks like 3 dicts, not 1, with some invalid Python syntax mixed in. `Dict2`, I assume, is missing `OrderedDict([`.  Also, have you written code to try to solve this problem yourself? If so, post the code and explain how it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant that you have a list of `OrderedDict`s:

`z = [j['name'] for j, k in zip(d1, d2.keys()) if j[k] == d2[k]]`

```
d1 = [
    OrderedDict([('name', 'John'), ('Score1', '2'), ('Score2', '8'), ('Score3', '3')]),
    OrderedDict([('name', 'Jack'), ('Score1', '4'), ('Score2', '1'), ('Score3', '5')]),
    OrderedDict([('name', 'Jill'), ('Score1', '1'), ('Score2', '2'), ('Score3', '5')])
]
    
d2 = OrderedDict([('Score1', '4'), ('Score2', '1'), ('Score3', '5')])

z = [j['name'] for j, k in zip(d1, d2.keys()) if j[k] == d2[k]]
>>> z
['Jack', 'Jill']
```